# hotkey to toggle between workspaces

Tags: workspaces, window, workflow

I want to toggle between two workspaces , ctr + alt + up/down doesn't suit me, because it requires two hands and I would prefer just a toggle hotkey like alt + ` or something to use with left hand.

explanation why i want this- im learning to code and technically i want to toggle between one chrome window with youtube lesson , and  other set would be different chrome window split screen with code editor.  So i guess workspaces are best option for this. Or maybe you have other suggestion for this workflow? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you set a dfferent shortcut in Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts?

Comment: GNOME extension `Workspace Indicator` will provide some functionality to the top bar with an option to switch to another one.

Comment: @pLumo yes i can , thanks. but what about a toggle for workplaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need workspaces for that. The Alt+tab task switcher can be set to work across desktops, so you can simply switch to a window on another workspace using <kbd>Alt/Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

**Option 1: Minor change**

You could achieve this simply by changing the Alt+Tab Window switcher, that stock Ubuntu uses by default, to  cover all workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

Reset this setting to the default setting by changing `set` to `reset` and leave out the value of the setting (`true` in this case).

This quickly may become impractical because the list of windows quickly can become large. Unless you are very disciplined and close any window you not immediately need, you may prefer to try the way it is handled in stock Gnome.

**Option 2: Major change: revert to behavior of Stock Gnome**

In stock gnome, you switch between applications across desktops with <kbd>Alt/Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and between windows of the same application across desktops with <kbd>Alt/Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. This is how you change task switching in Ubuntu to behave like stock Gnome Shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward "['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Above_Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "[]"
```

Again, you can undo as indicated above.

**Option 3 - what you actually asked: change key binding**

Change the relevant shortcut keys in "Settings - Keyboard".